# 'In the belief' or 'under the belief'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was doing a grammar Multiple Choice Question in a top school examination paper and I came across a question:

> Mr. Mohan is __________ the belief that artificial intelligence changes the way we work, so he encourages his children to keep up with the technological advancements.

With the following options for the missing word:

1. in
2. of
3. with
4. under

I chose (4). [The answer key said it was (3) and I didn't believe it.]

Which is the correct answer?

Comment: I would use _is of the belief that_, certainly not _with_. We can also say _He did this in the belief that [something was true]_.

Comment: Are you sure the question didn't ask for the one answer that could not fit? That would be #3, *with*.  All others are usable.

Comment: @Graffito - But your Ngram is for _[blank] the belief that_, not _is [blank] the belief that_ , which is a slightly different idiom.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I'm pretty sure. I've been doing MCQs for the past six years in Primary School.

Comment: @KateBunting:: Indeed, [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+in+the+belief+that%2Cis+on+the+belief+that%2Cis+under+the+belief+that%2Cis+with+the+belief+that%2Cis+of+the+belief+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) then supports the use of "of".

Answer (score 1):

A [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) search for `BE PREP the belief` gives the following results for each preposition:

1. *in*: False positives
2. *of*: Overwhelmingly preferred (~66 results)
3. *with*: False positive (one result for "impressed…with")
4. *under*: Some matches, but not as many (~14 results). I think that this may be coming from people drawing parallels with "BE under the impression…" which I personally find a lot more idiomatic than "BE under the belief…"

I see no justification for #3, not in American English at least.

Comment: Alright... so if it were you, what answer would you put then?

Comment: @YunQi_Crystal "of"

Comment: Got it, thank you :)